# several languages in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I want to implement several languages on one site (codeigniter framework). There are four country flags in the design. When user click on any flag the page should load the information in chosen language. There is no registration on the site (The site is quite simple).

I'd like my url's to be like this: http://site.com/en/controller/

What's the best(most simple) way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Code Igniter guide for this here:

[CI Wiki: Internationalizing the Language class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Internationalizing-the-Language-class/)

[Internationalization and the Template Parser Class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Internationalization-and-the-Template-Parser-Class)

Unfortunately no web framework will "solve" this for you, it can only make it easier. Content will be replicated in the languages, etc. What this does is help you make in parallel the M_C portion of the site. The views will need to all be translated still by you.